# How to fix Terraform Provider configuration not present

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using Terraform v1.2.5 I am attempting to deploy an AWS VPC Peer. However, the following code fails validation:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.1"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_vpc" "accepter" {
    provider = aws.accepter
    id = "${var.accepter_vpc_id}"
}

locals {
    accepter_account_id = "${element(split(":", data.aws_vpc.accepter.arn), 4)}"
}

resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "requester" {
  description   = "peer_to_${var.accepter_profile}"
  vpc_id        = "{$var.requester_vpc_id}"
  peer_vpc_id   = "${data.aws_vpc.accepter.id}"
  peer_owner_id = "${local.accepter_account_id}"
}
```

When validating this terraform code I am receiving the following error :

```
$ terraform validate
╷
│ Error: Provider configuration not present
│
│ To work with data.aws_vpc.accepter its original provider configuration at provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].accepter is
│ required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider configuration is removed while objects created by that provider still exist
│ in the state. Re-add the provider configuration to destroy data.aws_vpc.accepter, after which you can remove the provider configuration
│ again.
```

What am I missing or misconfigured that is causing this error?

Comment: By using an alias as you need to accept the peering connection in the accepter account.

Comment: I added `resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter" "accepter"` and get previous error plus a similar error referencing aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter.accepter.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the aliased provider version you are referencing here:

```
data "aws_vpc" "accepter" {
    provider = aws.accepter # <--- missing aliased provider
    id = var.accepter_vpc_id
}
```

To fix this, you just need to add the corresponding aliased provider block [1]:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "accepter"
  region = "us-east-1" # make sure the region is right
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations

Answer (score 0):

Since VPC Peering is an "inter-region" Peering we need 2 AWS regions. Hence the way to achhieve this is creating AWS provider and AWS alias provider blocks.

See an example:

```html
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"

  # Requester's credentials.
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "peer"
  region = "us-west-2"

  # Accepter's credentials.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your resource doesn't know what provider to use, the one you provided does not exist.

You have two options:

1. Add alias to provider:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  alias = "accepter"
}
```

2. remove line `provider = aws.accepter` from `data "aws_vpc" "accepter"`

Somehow, the first will be more valid for you, I suppose.